# Tehillim for a general bracha for someone else

Tags: tehilim-psalms

I want to be able to say  a perek (or a few perakim) of Tehillim to daven for a general bracha for a friend. Not anything specific, just that Hashem answer their requests and generally bless them.

What should I recite?

Comment: If you're looking to say one paragraph, then chapter 119 is the longest, so most Torah study points.

Answer (score 2):

I'm uncertain where I heard this, but [Tehillim 20](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14255&st=&pgnum=73) seems to be an excellent choice. The main reason being verse 6 which ends with

> ימלא ה כל משאלותיך
>
> May G-d fill all your requests